# Issue with web pack when trying to create React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to run React app following one tutorial, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm,  but I have some issues running the react app.
More precisely please find the error I get below when I type `npm start`

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-62-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --port 7000  --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --port 7000  --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --port 7000  --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs reactapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "demo app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 7000  --hot"
  },
  "author": "david",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

and this is webpack.config.js

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 7000,

   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It is missing one of the commands that need to be executed .. kindly execute the following command for installation,

```
npm install –save-dev webpack-dev-server webpack
```

Though they mention to install webpack server, it is missing with some command-line arguments

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you getting more error info? I'm also seeing:

```
Error: `output.path` needs to be an absolute path or `/`.
    at Object.setFs (node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/Shared.js:88:11)
    at Shared (node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/Shared.js:214:8)
    at module.exports (node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/middleware.js:22:15)
    at new Server (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:56:20)
    at startDevServer (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:354:12)
    at processOptions (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:318:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:419:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

Your output path in the webpack configuration is not absolute, you can easily solve that by adding `__dirname` like this:

```js
var config = {
   // ...
   output: {
      path: __dirname + '/build',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
   // ...
}
// ...
```

(I'd suggest you put the output in a separate directory like `build`.)

See also http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename

Comment: try to solve the problem rather than telling the standard how to 
 to write the config file.

Comment: @SKG in case it wasn't clear, the solution would be to change the `output` `path` in webpack.config.js to include `__dirname`. I wonder what happens if the original poster uses the output path mentioned here.